# In a hash map, I store key as one class object and value as another class object, how I'll retrieve the 5th value of the map?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, data-structures, collections

> In a hash map, if I will store key as one class object and value as another class object, how I will retrieve the value which is store for 5th key in hash map.

Comment: Define '5th'. Fifth by key order? Insertion order? Phase of the moon?

Comment: I want to get the value(object) , which is store for 5th key in hash map.

Answer (score 3):

A HashMap is not ordered, so there is no 5th value of the map. You can iterate over the `values()` Collection and get the 5th value, but the value you'll get will be arbitrary.

If you want "the 5th value of the map" to have a meaning :

- You can use a TreeMap, in which the keys are returning in sorted order when iterating over them.
- If you want to iterate over the keys in the order they were added to the map, you can use a LinkedHashMap.

Comment: Or you could use a LinkedHashMap, that keeps the order of elements.